Analog between Electromagnetism and Gravity
Feynman makes an analogy between EM field and gravity field in his Feynman's Lectures on Gravitation. The vector field representing EM potential would couple to the current source(vector) in the Lagrangian.
$$A^{\mu}J_{\mu}$$
And the EOM in momentum space is
$$A^{\mu} = \frac{1}{k^2}J^{\mu}\tag{1}$$
Similarly, the tensor field representing interaction would couple to a tensor source,
$$h^{\mu\nu}T_{\mu\nu}$$
and the EOM in momentum space is
$$h^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{k^2}T^{\mu\nu}\tag{2}$$
Now, we know the Lagrangian of EM field respects gauge invariance,
$$A^{\mu}\rightarrow A^{\mu} + \partial^{\mu}\alpha$$
Then we have the current source should be conserved,
$$\partial_{\mu}J^{\mu} = 0\tag{3}$$
The physical meaning of current can be associated to Noether's current of the gauge symmetry.
However, Feynman didn't mention above connection of current to gauge invariance but merely impose the conserved equation.
In the case of gravitation, the tensor source is also conserved,
$$\partial_{\mu}T^{\mu\nu} = 0\tag{4}$$
And later he claims the tensor source in gravitation field theory would be stress-energy.
I would like to ask, how does Feynman identify the tensor source as stress-energy?
And is the conserved eq.(4) also associated to the gauge symmetry in gravitation theory?
Then how to connect the idea of gauge symmetry to the stress-energy, which should associated to the space-time symmetry in Noether's theorem?
Something like making space-time symmetry local?

In electromagnetism, if you have a
$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4} F^2 + A_\mu J^\mu
$$
where $F^2=F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ is the Maxwell term ($F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$), the first term is manifestly invariant under gauge transformations $A_\mu \rightarrow A_\mu + \partial_\mu \lambda$. But the second term is only gauge invariant if the current is conserved, since under a gauge transformation $A_\mu J^\mu \rightarrow A_\mu J^\mu + \partial_\mu \lambda J^\mu$. Integrating by parts in the action and dropping the boundary term, the non-invariant term becomes $-\lambda \partial_\mu J^\mu$, which is zero if $J$ is conserved. So, there is a connection between gauge invariance, and a conserved current.
We know $h_{\mu\nu}$ should couple to a symmetric tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$. Now, the "kinetic term" for $h$ (quadratic lagrangian) has a gauge symmetry where
$$
h_{\mu\nu} \rightarrow h_{\mu\nu} + \partial_\mu \xi_\nu + \partial_\nu \xi_\mu
$$
which is a linearized form of diffeomorphism invariance, also called invariance under general coordinate transformations. Again, running the argument above, the coupling term $h_{\mu\nu} T^{\mu\nu}$ will only be gauge invariant if $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$=0.
If you're happy to accept that the spin-2 field is going to be related to gravity, then $T_{\mu\nu}$ being the stress-energy tensor is pretty natural; that's the natural relativistic generalization of having the gravitational field couple to mass in Newtonian theory. If you aren't, then all we know about $T^{\mu\nu}$ is that it is a symmetric, conserved tensor. Then the point is that the only symmetric, conserved 2-index tensor that's "lying around", so to speak, is the stress-energy tensor.
Diffeomorphism invariance is sort of like a local version of spacetime translations/boosts/rotations in Minkowski space, but the group structure is quite different. There's an alternative formulation of general relativity called Einstein-Cartan theory which uses the frame field or vielbein $e^a_\mu$ (related to the metric via $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{ab}e^a_\mu e^b_\nu$, where $\eta_{ab}$ is the Minkowski metric), where the connection to gauge theory is more direct. In that formalism, you can think of the vielbein and spin connection fields as being gauge fields from gauging the Poincaire group (global isometry group of Minkowski spacetime).
Finally, where Feynman is headed with this is constructing consistent interactions of the graviton field by using the requirement of conservation of $T^\mu_{\,\,\,\,\nu}$ up to a given order to figure out what kinds of interactions are allowed. This procedure for constructing consistent interactions for a gauge field by using symmetry requirements is sometimes known as the Noether procedure.
